# How to configure ESLint-HTML reporter with jest?

Tags: windows, npm, jestjs, eslint, frisby.js

I want to configure ESLint-HTML reporter with package.json of jest and nothing on the sites of ESlint or on the jest.So,i'm not able to run scripts by passing jest through CMD.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this: I tried and it worked for me

```
 "jest-stare": {
            "merge": "true",
            "resultDir": "results/jest-stare",
            "log": "true",
            "resultHtml": "main.html",
            "resultJson": "data.json",
            "jestStareConfigJson": "jest-stare-config.json",
            "coverageLink": "../../coverage/lcov-report/index.html"
        }
```